# How to guarantee both parts of if statement run?

Tags: javascript

I have an if statement that resizes my background video to match the browser window height and width, though sometimes it doesn't work, and will only match either the height or the width. I am relatively sure this can be remedied by making sure that both the if clause and else clause run no matter what.  I thought about nesting it in a for loop, but that didnt seem like a good solution.

Here is my code.

JS:

```
var resizeVideo = function() {

    var fullWidth = window.innerWidth;
    var fullHeight = window.innerHeight;

    var video = document.getElementById("test");
    var videoWidth = video.style.width;
    var videoHeight = video.style.height;

    console.log(videoHeight);
    console.log(fullHeight);

    var fired = false;        
    if(parseInt(video.style.height, 10) <= window.innerHeight && fired == false) {
        video.style.height = fullHeight + 'px';
        var fullWidthAdjusted = fullHeight * 1.7777777;
        video.style.width = fullWidthAdjusted + 'px';
        console.log(videoWidth);
        console.log("Height correction working");
        fired = true;
    } else {
        video.style.width = fullWidth + 'px';
        var fullHeightAdjusted = fullWidth * .5625;
        video.style.height = fullHeightAdjusted + 'px';
        console.log("Width correction working");
        fired = true;
    }
};

window.onresize = resizeVideo;
window.onload = resizeVideo;
```

Comment: But do you me that both the `if` and the `else` should run? That is the whole idea of an if / else statement, that NOT both will run.

Comment: If you need both chunks of code to run, why use if/else?

Comment: The whole point of if/else is to be one or the other. If you want some piece of code to run no matter what, pull it out of the statement...

Comment: To comment on your code more appropriately, you should have one if statement for width only, and one if statement for height only, one after the other.

Comment: Is this not possible with just CSS?

Comment: Okay, ya'll were right.  An if statement was not the way to go, on this one.  At least not the way I had it structured.

Answer (score 2):

`if .. else` is there to execute either one piece of code or another. In your case, both might need to be executed, depending on the situation, so you'll need two separate if statements, each with their own condition.

```
// You can, but don't have to, introduce a variable for this.
// I like it, because it makes the condition more readable and a bit more
// self-documenting, but you might just as well put it in the 'if' as you did.
var heightChanged = parseInt(video.style.height, 10) <= window.innerHeight;
var widthChanged = parseInt(video.style.width, 10) <= window.innerWidth;

if (heightChanged) {
    video.style.height = fullHeight + 'px';
    var fullWidthAdjusted = fullHeight * 1.7777777;
    video.style.width = fullWidthAdjusted + 'px';
    console.log(videoWidth);
    console.log("Height correction working");
} 

if (widthChanged) {
    video.style.width = fullWidth + 'px';
    var fullHeightAdjusted = fullWidth * .5625;
    video.style.height = fullHeightAdjusted + 'px';
    console.log("Width correction working");
}
```

I eliminated the 'fired' variable, since it didn't really do anything in your code.

Alternatively, you might want to have a look at the article [Proportional Resizing of Web Page Elements Using Only CSS](http://wellcaffeinated.net/articles/2012/06/26/proportional-resizing-of-web-page-elements-using-only-css/).

Comment: the `fired` condition makes no sense, it is literally defined (assigned) right before it is tested

Comment: @musefan Is that compiler-sp34k for *"you made a typo, forgot an `=`"*?

Comment: Ha, no. I didn't even notice that. I meant it makes no sense to evaluate `fired == false` as it is always set to false prior to the condition

Comment: @musefan Well it wasn't in my version. ;)  But you're right. It seems to have no use, so I eliminated it from this code. Thanks.